# bounding the second largest eigenvalue of a regular graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, reference-request, spectral-graph-theory

I read that the second largest eigenvalue of a graph is always positive except for 
specific classes of graphs, i.e the graphs that have second largest eigenvalue smaller than zero are fully characterized.

I was not able to figure out this question completely by browsing the web and looking at papers I found.

Any reference or full answer would be of great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you're looking for, from the unfortunately-not-online paper "Some properties of the spectrum of a graph" by J.H. Smith (1970), is the following:

> **Theorem.** A graph has exactly one positive eigenvalue if and only if its non-isolated vertices form a complete multipartite graph.

I found a proof of this as Theorem 6.7 in *Spectra of Graphs: Theory and Application* by Cvetković, Doob, and Sachs.

**Proof, part 1.** Here, we show that all graphs *not* of this form have at least two positive eigenvalues. We ignore isolated vertices, since these just contribute eigenvalues of $0$ to our graph, and let $G$ be the subgraph where all of these are removed.

Complete multipartite graphs are precisely the ones in which the relation of non-adjacency between vertices is transitive. If this is not true of $G$, then there must be vertices $x,y,z$ such that $\{x,y\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ are non-edges, but $\{x,z\}$ is an edge. Since $y$ is not isolated, it has a neighbor $w$, and by casework on $w$'s possible adjacencies to $x$ and $z$, we conclude that $G$ must have one of the following as an induced subgraph:

[image: induced subgraphs]

Each of these has two positive eigenvalues $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ and by the interlacing theorem, $G$ must have two positive eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ge \mu_1$ and $\lambda_2 \ge \mu_2$. (Actually, the worst case is the third graph, and we can compute that $\mu_2 > 0.3111$ in that case, getting a more specific lower bound on the second eigenvalue.)

**Proof, part 2.** Here, we show that all complete multipartite graphs have only one positive eigenvalue. For this, the authors of *Spectra of Graphs* cite a characteristic polynomial calculation which can be found in Cvetković's Ph.D. thesis (possibly in Serbian). You can find out more about the spectra of complete multipartite graphs from [Esser and Harary (1980)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669880800047), if you really want to. But we don't actually need to know the full spectrum here, so there's a shortcut.

Let $\mathbf x$ be the eigenvector of an eigenvalue of a complete multipartite graph, with partition $V_1 \cup \dots \cup V_p$. Let $S_i = \sum_{v \in V_i} x_v$ and $S = S_1 + \dots + S_p$. The eigenvector condition says that if $v \in V_i$, then $\sum_{w \notin V_i} x_w = S - S_i = \lambda x_v$. In particular, when $\lambda \ne 0$, $x_v = \frac{S - S_i}{\lambda}$ is constant over all $v \in V_i$, and $S = S_i + \lambda x_v = (|V_i| + \lambda) x_v$.

Suppose $\lambda > 0$, and yet $\lambda$ is **not** the largest eigenvalue.
By the [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem_for_irreducible_non-negative_matrices), the eigenvector of $\lambda$ cannot have all its entries strictly positive (or all strictly negative). Negating $\mathbf x$ if necessary, we can find $v \in V_i$ and $w \in V_j$ such that $x_v > 0$ and $x_w \le 0$. Then $S = (|V_i| + \lambda) x_v > 0$, yet $S = (|V_j| + \lambda) x_w < 0$; a contradiction.

So the non-leading eigenvalues cannot be positive. In fact, this same argument shows that after the leading eigenvalue and some number of zero eigenvalues, the next eigenvalue is at most $-\min_i |V_i|$.