# Some tripartite graphs and DS graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory

I know $K_{n,n,n}$ is determined by its adjacency spectrum (by using its regularity) and I know complete multipartite graphs are not determined by their adjacency spectra, in general. What about $K_{1,n,n}$ and $K_{1,1,n}$ (complete tripartite graphs)? are  they determined by the spectra of their adjacency matrices? I think thay are DS ( determined by the adjacency spectrum) but I can't find a reference for that or prove it. Does anyone know if there is a reference for this? Or a refrence for complete tripartite graphs?
Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spectrum of $K_{1,n,n}$ or $K_{1,1,n}$, we can determine:

- That a graph with that spectrum is a complete multipartite graph, possibly with isolated vertices added. (Such graphs are the only ones with exactly one positive eigenvalue; see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230329/bounding-the-second-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-regular-graph).)
- That in fact the complete multipartite component is a tripartite graph $K_{a,b,c}$, by the count of nonzero eigenvalues. (The isolated vertices will only add some number of $0$ eigenvalues.)
- We also know that $ab+ac+bc$, the number of edges of the $K_{a,b,c}$ component, must match the number of edges in $K_{1,n,n}$ or $K_{1,1,n}$ respectively. The edge count is determined by the eigenvalues.

Esser and Harary's [On the spectrum of a complete multipartite graph](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(80)80004-7) tells us more: the negative eigenvalues of $K_{a,b,c}$ with $a \le b \le c$ are $\lambda_{a+b+c-1} \in [-b,-a]$ and $\lambda_{a+b+c} \in [-c,-b]$. They also give some guarantees on strictness, of which we only need one: if $a < b$, then $\lambda_{a+b+c-1} \in (-b,-a)$.

This is enough to deal with $K_{1,1,n}$, which has an eigenvalue of $-1$. For $K_{a,b,c}$ to have an eigenvalue of $-1$, we must have $a=1$ (since $\lambda_{a+b+c-1} \le -a$) and $b=1$ (or else $\lambda_{a+b+c-1} < a$). But no $K_{1,1,c}$ with $c \ne n$ has the same number of edges as $K_{1,1,n}$.

For $K_{1,n,n}$, we get a negative eigenvalue of $\frac{n - \sqrt{n^2+8n}}{2} \in (-2,-1]$, so any potential cospectral mate with a tripartite component of $K_{a,b,c}$ must have $a=1$, too. Also, the number of edges must match $K_{1,n,n}$: $b + c + bc = 2n + n^2$, or $(b+1)(c+1) = (n+1)^2$. But from this, it follows that $b+c\ge 2n$, with equality only if $b=c=n$, so any other tripartite graph $K_{1,b,c}$ with $2n+n^2$ edges has more vertices than $K_{1,n,n}$.

---

In fact, cospectral mates of complete tripartite graphs are pretty rare. The smallest example I found was $K_{5,6,20}$, which has the same spectrum as $K_{4,10,15} \cup 2K_1$. They do exist, though :)

Another approach to the problem, once we've figured out that we're looking for something of the form $K_{a,b,c} \cup d K_1$, is to compute the characteristic polynomial: it is
$$
    \pm x^{a+b+c+d-3}(x^3 - (ab + ac + bc)x - 2abc).
$$
So $K_{a,b,c}$ and $K_{a',b',c'}$ are "cospectral up to isolated vertices" iff $ab + ac + bc = a'b' + a'c' + b'c'$ and $abc = a'b'c'$.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your complete answer. I have two questions. " if a<b, then $\lambda_{a+b+c−1}\in (−b,−a)$ ." What did we use this fact for? Another one, Cospectral graphs have the same edges? I think the answer is yes, because of the sum of square of eigenvalues equals to twice of edges. Is it correct?

Comment: (1) We use this to say that $\lambda_{a+b+c-1} = -1$ implies not just $a=1$ but $a=b=1$. (2) Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think in this proof we should add some isolated vertices to the $K_{a,b,c}$, is this correct?

Comment: We are adding them, but I am ignoring them in the calculations, because they don't affect the nonzero eigenvalues. (The right number of isolated vertices to add is always whatever would make the total number of vertices the same.)